# How to use terraform module outputs as input variable for different environments

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a situation where I need to pass output from terraform module to different environments. I have a folder structure as below:

> ```
> shared_modules
>     - lambda
>     - cloudwatch
>     - vpc
> ```

From these modules, I am able to output the values of created resources like `lambda_notify_arn, sns_topic_notify_arn`
Now I have different environments like:

> environments
>
> - production
> - non-production

I want to use the output value of `lambda_notify_arn, sns_topic_notify_arn` from shared_mosules to each of the environments without creating resources.

How to achieve this?

If I call modules like below, it will try to recreate existing resources and throws an error

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "../shared_modules/vpc"
  .........
}
```

For resource creation, my script run terraform apply from shared_modules first and then cd into environments and run terraform apply

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read those output values directly using [terraform_remote_state](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/state/remote-state-data) within your environment-specific Terraform code, to read values from the shared_modules state, but this has always felt like a hack to me, or at least a bad practice.

---

Ideally you could use [data sources](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/data-sources) in your environment-specific Terraform code to look up the values that are needed. You mentioned you needed an AWS Lambda ARN, and an SNS topic ARN, and you could look those up with the [aws_lambda_function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/lambda_function) datasource, and the [aws_sns_topic](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/sns_topic) datasource. You would just need to pass in, or hard-code, the lambda function name and the SNS topic name.

---

Another option would be to have your `shared_modules` Terraform code create some [SSM Parameter Store](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/ssm_parameter) values to store those ARNs, and have your environment-specific Terraform code [read those values](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/data-sources/ssm_parameter).

---

The final option would be to pass those as input variables and do something like the following every time you run your environment-specific Terraform code:

```
terraform apply \
  -var lambda_arn=$(terraform -chdir=../shared_modules output -raw lambda_notify_arn) \
  -var sns_arn=$(terraform -chdir=../shared_modules output -raw sns_topic_notify_arn )
```

This solution is slow, because it runs `terraform` state lookups multiple times before even running the `terraform apply`, and obviously way too much to type every time you want to apply some infrastructure change. You would have to wrap this in a shell script if you went with this method.

Comment: I liked the first solution, using terraform_remote_state. I will try this now and update it here. I tried data_sources already but was getting an error for lambda function .... not found.

Comment: If the lambda function is not found by the data source, then you have the function's name wrong. Data sources are the best solution to this, and should definitely work. Post more info in your question if you need help getting that to work.

Comment: You are right Mark, there was a function name mismatch that I was using as a data source. It is working fine now.

Thanks, @Mark